# What CUDA version does torch/lua require?

Tags: lua, torch

I'm trying to install Torch/Lua version and am getting the build errors shown below. I see this discussion on Github encountering the same errors, but I don't see a resolution to it.

https://github.com/torch/torch7/issues/670

What version of CUDA does torch require? My best guess right now is that this is a CUDA version mismatch.

CMake Error at THC_generated_THCBlas.cu.o.cmake:267 (message):
  Error generating file

```
~/torch/extra/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCBlas.cu.o


CMake Error at THC_generated_THCSleep.cu.o.cmake:267 (message):
  Error generating file
  ~/torch/extra/cutorch/build/lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir//./THC_generated_THCSleep.cu.o


lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/build.make:392: recipe for target 'lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCBlas.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/THC/CMakeFiles/THC.dir/THC_generated_THCBlas.cu.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that these issues were related to the `g++` version I had (4.8). I installed the latest `g++` version (5.2), then had to delete the torch directory, re-clone it, and the installation worked. Note that build artifacts will be left over so actually removing the whole torch directory was necessary.